# removing valueStateText value from dropdown list in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have put a `valueStateText` on dropdown for each value. but the valueStateText shows above the dropdown list(as in pic where "Entry success..."is valueStateText). Can we remove it from the list only without removing valueStateText?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `valueStateText` prop will be visible on the sap.m.Select control only if the value of `valueState!="None"`

In other words if you need to "remove it from the list and keep the valueStateText prop"

just make sure to update the sap.m.Select control with `valueState="None"`

Comment: if  i set valueState to 'none' valueStateText is also gone

Comment: You should be able to use `setValueState('None')` this should not affect the valueStateText prop
To verify check it with `getValueStateText()`